# Calling super's forward() method

Tags: python, pytorch, super

What is the most appropriate way to call the `forward()` method of a parent `Module`? For example, if I subclass the `nn.Linear` module, I might do the following

```
class LinearWithOtherStuff(nn.Linear):
    def forward(self, x):
        y = super(Linear, self).forward(x)
        z = do_other_stuff(y)
        return z
```

However, the [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.Module.forward) say not to call the `forward()` method directly:

> Although the recipe for forward pass needs to be defined within this function, one should call the Module instance afterwards instead of this since the former takes care of running the registered hooks while the latter silently ignores them.

which makes me think `super(Linear, self).forward(x)` could result in some unexpected errors. Is this true or am I misunderstanding inheritance?

Comment: Note that this is more a question about the semantics of `Module.forward` than it is about `super`.

Comment: The docstring for `Module` shows an example subclass that doesn't call `Module.forward` at all. It sounds like `Module.__call__` takes care of adding the `forward` method to a list of hooks that get called automatically, rather than being something you need to call explicitly yourself.

Comment: Is there a special reason to use inheritance instead of composition?

Comment: e.g. if `do_other_stuff(y)` modifies an instance variable of `LinearWithOtherStuff`

Answer (score 5):

### TLDR;

You can use `super().forward(...)` freely even with hooks and even with hooks registered in `super()` instance.

### Explanation

As stated [by this answer](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/any-different-between-model-input-and-model-forward-input/3690/2) `__call__` is here so the registered hooks (e.g. [`register_forward_hook`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.register_forward_hook)) will be run.

If you inherit and want to reuse base class's `forward`, e.g. this:

```
import torch


class Parent(torch.nn.Module):
    def forward(self, tensor):
        return tensor + 1


class Child(Parent):
    def forward(self, tensor):
        return super(Child, self).forward(tensor) + 1


module = Child()
# Increment output by 1 so we should get `4`
module.register_forward_hook(lambda module, input, output: output + 1)
print(module(torch.tensor(1))) # and it is 4 indeed
print(module.forward(torch.tensor(1))) # here it is 3 still
```

You are perfectly fine if you call `__call__` method, `forward` won't run the hook (so you get `3` as above).

It is unlikely you would like to `register_hook` on the instance of `super` , but let's consider such example:

```
def increment_by_one(module, input, output):
    return output + 1


class Parent(torch.nn.Module):
    def forward(self, tensor):
        return tensor + 1


class Child(Parent):
    def forward(self, tensor):
        # Increment by `1` from Parent
        super().register_forward_hook(increment_by_one)
        return super().forward(tensor) + 1


module = Child()
# Increment output by 1 so we should get `5` in total
module.register_forward_hook(increment_by_one)
print(module(torch.tensor(1)))  # and it is 5 indeed
print(module.forward(torch.tensor(1)))  # here is 3
```

You are perfectly fine using `super().forward(...)` and even hooks will work correctly (and that is the main idea of using `__call__` instead of `forward`).

**BTW.**  Calling `super().__call__(...)` would raise `InifiniteRecursion` error.

Comment: This works ootb for instances where torch module is directly used, but when using torchscript jit, it throws error as `'Tensor' object has no attribute or method 'forward'.`. i.e. `model_scripted = torch.jit.script(model)` and doing a call with data show this error.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the minimal `M0` module in PyTorch. Nothing in there (no other modules).
What they said about `forward()` is you should not call it directly, instead it is called automatically when you instantiate the module and execute the module `m0()`

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class M0(nn.Module):    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    
    def forward(self)->None: 
        print("empty module:forward")
        
# we create a module instance m1
m0 = M0()
m0()
# ??m0.__call__ # has forward() inside
```

Out:

```
empty module:forward
```

In case you would like to have submodules you would aggregate them:

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class M1(nn.Module):    
    ''' 
    Single linear layer
    '''
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.l1 = nn.Linear(10,100)        
    
    def forward(self,x): 
        print("M1:forward")
        x = self.l1(x) 
        return x
        
# we create a module instance m1
m1 = M1()
print(m1)
inp = torch.randn(1,10)
r = m1(inp) # result
print(r.shape)
```

Out:

```
M1(
  (l1): Linear(in_features=10, out_features=100, bias=True)
)
M1:forward
torch.Size([1, 100])
```

Once you aggregate other modules, you call `forward()` to execute them. `forward()` will need the input and will return some output.

This model was originally presented in Lua programming language, and PyTorch just used that.

---

> ### which makes me think super(Linear, self).forward(x) could result in some unexpected errors

This is exactly why `forward()` is not called directly to suppress these unexpected errors. Instead, modules are callable like we did in the example:

```
self.l1(x)
```

Comment: While technically correct (and interesting thing about lua, thanks) it misses the point of this question as we're talking inheritance specifically, not composition.

Comment: It was not meant to work with inheritance in mind. So the idea of inheritance was not the original concept and I haven't set any attention on it.

Comment: Pytorch was meant with inheritance in mind (although that isn't the case most often) and uses it often throughout the repository. OP clearly is asking about inheritance (see his code snippet and `super()` use) and reusing parent's `forward` hence this answer does not answer his question.

Comment: Inheritance is mentioned in the question but as far as I see the main question was: "What is the most appropriate way to call the forward() method of a parent Module?". IMO this shaping creates space for alternative answers. Correct me if I am wrong. I am doing hard deleting this answer as I expect it could help others creating good running solutions.

Comment: @JonathanStellwag Never heard of "parent" being used in context of composition, inheritance only. Also I don't think inheritance is merely mentioned, __it is the only thing OP is asking about__. IMO it's perfectly clear OP is after inheritance, e.g.
"if I subclass the nn.Linear module" and __his code snippets not using composition even once__ (inheritance only with `super()`). This answer is totally offtopic and noise in this context. Also please @ me next time so I can answer you sooner, thanks.